# Is the Google auth documentation out of date? Is the Google QuickStart guides still relevant for Gmail API?

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-ruby-client

I am using a command line Ruby script to access emails in a Gmail inbox.

The documentation is here for the Google Auth library for Ruby: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby

The Ruby QuickStart guide for Gmail API is here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby

Both sets of documentation uses an OOB URI in `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`, which Google says is being deprecated here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/oob-migration#what-is-oob

I can't find any helpful documentation to help me migrate over. Please help.

Comment: I've found a duplicate thread and have marked this as a duplicate.